# How to access data from http.get method nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple http.get request to external api.
How can I access id and name variables from another function? Thanks!

```js
app.use(function *(next){

 var name = '';
 var id = '';

 var options = {
  host: 'www.website.com',
  path: '/json/somedata',
  metohd: 'GET'
 };
 http.get(options, function(res) {

  var body = '';

  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
   body+=chunk;
   console.log(body);
  })
  res.on('end', function() {
   var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            id = parsed.id;
            name = parsed.name;
  })
 })
});
```

Comment: The http library is pretty low level.  I recommend you have a look at request on npm, it behaves a bit more like you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the npm module express, with the syntax you have there.

Your answer depends on where you are looking to use id and name.  If you are trying to use it in a route or middleware **after** this one a common way to solve that problem is to attach the properties (in this case name and id) to the request.  Remember to call next after you are finished otherwise express will not know you have finished all your processing

I've given a quick example below:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){

   var options = {
       host: 'www.website.com',
       path: '/json/somedata',
       method: 'GET'
   };
   http.get(options, function(getResponse) {

    var body = '';

    getResponse.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body+=chunk;
        console.log(body);
    })
    getResponse.on('end', function() {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
        req.id = parsed.id;
        req.name = parsed.name;
        next();

    })
    })
});
```